# How does RecursiveAction work with Fibonacci?

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

How does recursion work in case of Fibonacci. The below example uses RecursiveAction which does not return any value. But still it is possible to calculate Fibonacci numbers. I mean for example in case of Fibonacci(15). The threshold in below example is 10. So Fibonacci(15) cannot be calculated directly. So 2 other tasks will be created . ForkJoinFibonacci(n - 1) and ForkJoinFibonacci(n - 2). So in the below example only the member variable "number" stores the calculated Fibonacci number. But it is never returned. Only stored locally in each ForkJoinFibonacci class.So how can all the calculated numbers be summed up ?

```
public class ForkJoinFibonacci extends RecursiveAction {
    
        private static final long threshold = 10;
        private volatile long number;
    
        public ForkJoinFibonacci(long number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    
        public long getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            long n = number;
            if (n <= threshold) {
                number = fib(n);
            } else {
                ForkJoinFibonacci f1 = new ForkJoinFibonacci(n - 1);
                ForkJoinFibonacci f2 = new ForkJoinFibonacci(n - 2);
                ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(f1, f2);
                number = f1.number + f2.number;
            }
        }
    
        private static long fib(long n) {
            if (n <= 1) return n;
            else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
    }
```

To make it clear. It works. But I just do not know why it works.

Comment: Did you try: `System.out.println(task.number);` ? After doing `ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(); int n = 13; ForkJoinFibonacci task = new ForkJoinFibonacci(n); fjp.invoke(task);`

Answer (score 1):

The summing is in the compute method.

Each recursive action stores its own calculation in number. the compute method either finishes the calculation if it's small enough, storing it in the number field, or farms the work out to two more recursive actions, in which case it gets their results from their number field, sums them, and stores them in its own number field. the topmost recursive action exposes number through a getter.

It probably isn't clear how compute gets called on both f1 and f2. The documentation for invokeAll says each of the tasks gets forked, that puts them in the work queue for the current task, and they're eligible for stealing by other threads. The important thing is that both f1 and f2 get processed and have compute run on them before control returns from invokeAll. Each time compute is called it retrieves the number fields from the completed forked tasks, sums them, and stores the result in its own number field.

One more thing making this confusing to read is that it's using number to store 2 different things, the number identifying which fibonacci number we're trying to calculate and also the result of the calculation.

The posted code does look like it should work, but it does not make the best use of its threads. An alternative way to write this is to replace the invokeAll with

```
f1.fork();
f2.compute();
f1.join();
```

That way the current thread is directly computing one branch of the subproblem instead of forking both of them.

Comment: Ok . But where in the compute() method ? As you said it just is stored in the variable "number". Where is it summed up ?? There is no return value.

Comment: @Toni26: see if my edit helps?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. On the first level I understand it. But with all the nesting I have problem understanding it. e.g new ForkJoinFibonacci(17) cannot be solved so it will become new ForkJoinFibonacci(16) and new ForkJoinFibonacci(15) and again these need to be split . So with nesting getting deeper I do not know how number will be returned to the topmost level and all numbers getting summed up. Number never gets returned just stored as member in class

Comment: @Toni26: yes but each level that does a compute pulls the numbers from the lower levels and adds them up, then stores the sum, so the next higher level can get it in turn.

Comment: @Toni26 "Number never gets returned" - they aren't returned explicitly, but rather directly accessed by the caller here `number = f1.number + f2.number` and that's happening up the hierarchy by each "parent" after the child tasks are completed

Comment: Finally I got it . Thanks a lot. I was also confused that "number" is private, but in Java the same class can still access it.

Comment: Ok I had that in my answer at one point...